# how to set day and night theme in android application

Tags: android

I have created an Android application that uses a list of preferences to set day and night mode theme.

My styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></style>

<style name="PreferencesTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#FFEAEAEA</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferencesTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ic_icon_settings</item>
</style>
```

Does anyone know how how I can apply night and day mode to my styles.xml

Answer (score 10):

You should look at the *HoneycombGallery* example from the Android 3.2 API13 sample applications.

They way they have implemented this is:

Declare two themes in your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar" />

<style name="ActionBar.Light" parent="@style/ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Dark" parent="@style/ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Light</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="menuIconCamera">@drawable/ic_menu_camera_holo_light</item>
    <item name="menuIconToggle">@drawable/ic_menu_toggle_holo_light</item>
    <item name="menuIconShare">@drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    <item name="menuIconCamera">@drawable/ic_menu_camera_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="menuIconToggle">@drawable/ic_menu_toggle_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="menuIconShare">@drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

*MENUS TO SWITCH BETWEEN THE MODES:*

This is the `main_menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/toggleTheme"
        android:title="Day/Night"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And the `MainActivity` class where they toggle between the *Day* and *Night* modes:

NOTE: I have stripped out the other stuff that is not necessary for the context of this question.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.toggleTheme:
        if (mThemeId == R.style.AppTheme_Dark) {
            mThemeId = R.style.AppTheme_Light;
        } else {
            mThemeId = R.style.AppTheme_Dark;
        }
        this.recreate();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The Global Variable necessary for switching between the modes:

```
private int mThemeId = -1;
```

And for saving the last selected *mode*, in the onCreate():

```
if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getInt("theme", -1) != -1) {
    mThemeId = savedInstanceState.getInt("theme");
    this.setTheme(mThemeId);
}
```

But do download the samples from the SDK Manager and see the actual (entire) functioning.

Comment: `Activity.recreate()` is only available from API 11 (Android 3.0)

Comment: no resource found for given name  *** <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>
        <item name="menuIconCamera">@drawable/ic_menu_camera_holo_light</item>
        <item name="menuIconToggle">@drawable/ic_menu_toggle_holo_light</item>
        <item name="menuIconShare">@drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>*** are in style

Comment: @NiravMehta: Do you have these images in your `Drawable` folder/r? If you don't, that error is pretty obvious. As mentioned at the start of the post, this is an example from the _Android 3.2 API13 sample applications_. you could just copy them from the _HoneycombGallery_ example. Or use other images and change the names in the `styles.xml`.