# how to set day Mode and Night Mode

Tags: android

Theme.class

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginRight="59dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i want set day and night theme on Button click in android. Please tell me how to do this. How create style and all. I am new in android. I tried many not able to do.

Comment: @vinil ll u please help me to set day and Night Mode Theme ?

Comment: @codo ll u please help me to set day and Night Mode Theme?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use proper upper/lowercase writing and punctuation next time. I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Do you want to turn night mode on and off for you app and/or your phone? Or do want to provide different UI styles for day and night mode? Or what exactly are you trying to achieve and where are you stuck?

Comment: i want set Night Mode and day mode in app

Comment: i want to set day mode and night so that user clcik on Button on daynight mode Button then it should change please help me please send it as dummy Example

Comment: @codo r u there? please help me dear

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164414/11158194

Answer (score 1):

Add to you `res` `values-night` and define `colors.xml`. In `Application` or `Activity` after `super.onCreate()` define 
`UiModeManager umm = (UiModeManager){#context}.getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
umm.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
//MODE_NIGHT_YES|MODE_NIGHT_NO|MODE_NIGHT_AUTO`

Official documentation - [UiModeManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html)

this code worked in API 23, in 19 may be no

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution in this answer: [how to set day and night theme in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13561786/1869865)

There is a complete functioning example available in the Samples for SDK, I believe, from API 11 to API 16 (I haven't downloaded the API 17 yet).

I have used the solution provided in the linked answer and it works.

Hope this helps you too.

Comment: I have Tried But Eror is coming when i Implement it wid my application

Comment: public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
 {
  switch (sTheme)
  {
  default:
  
  case THEME_WHITE:
   activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_White);
   break;
  case THEME_BLUE:
   activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Blue);
   break;
  }
 }
 in this Theme_White cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: how to fix this Error @Codo

Comment: I don't see how this code snippet is related to night mode. And it's missing a lot of context. Please open a new question, add all the relevant code and format it with the `{ }` button.