# How to have a properly Dark and Light Theme with Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have read that there is a way to have a values-night and a values folder. But how to change from values to values-night before starting ,because of my splash screen. I know that there must be a way to have a dark and light themed splash screen ,because of WhatsApp.

How to change to values-night before Splash Screen is shown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below dark mode code which I am use.

**Step - 1**

First of create **night** folder into your resource file like below image(i.e. values-night)

[image: Create night mode folder]

**Step - 2**

Create **styles,strings and colors** xml file for **night mode** same as below image and add your night mode color,string and style which you want to show in your app when night mode was apply.

[image: Create night mode xml files]

For better user experience add **window Animation** in your style.

**values --> style.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NoActionBarAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_click_txt</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Add this theme where you change mode -->
    <style name="NoActionBarWithChangeTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_click_txt</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- This will set the fade in animation on your change theme activity by default -->
    <style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**values-night --> style.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. values-night.xml -->
<style name="NoActionBarAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_click_txt</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
</style>

<!-- Add this theme where you change mode -->
<style name="NoActionBarWithChangeTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_click_txt</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
</style>

<!-- This will set the fade in animation on your change activity by default -->
<style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

**fade_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

**fade_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" >
    </alpha>
</set>
```

**Step - 3**

Add this below code in your **splash screen** if you want to **set night mode as per device mode** first time when application installed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (!CommonUtils.isToogleEnabled(SplashActivity.this)) {
        if (CommonUtils.isDarkMode(SplashActivity.this)) {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(SplashActivity.this, true);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        } else {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(SplashActivity.this, false);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    } else {
        if (CommonUtils.isNightModeEnabled(SplashActivity.this)) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    //your code
}
```

**Step - 4**

Add this below code in your all activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (CommonUtils.isNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this)) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    //your code
}
```

**Step - 5**

**Change mode** using below code

```
private WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;

binding.imgNightMode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(MainActivity.this);
        CommonUtils.setIsToogleEnabled(MainActivity.this, true);
        if (CommonUtils.isNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this)) {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this, false);
            mActivity.get().recreate();
        } else {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this, true);
            mActivity.get().recreate();
        }
    }
});
```

Below methods are **CommonUtils**.

```
private static final String NIGHT_MODE = "NIGHT_MODE";
private static final String TOOGLE = "TOOGLE";

public static boolean isNightModeEnabled(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return mPrefs.getBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, false);
}

public static void setIsNightModeEnabled(Context context, boolean isNightModeEnabled) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, isNightModeEnabled);
    editor.apply();
}

public static void setIsToogleEnabled(Context context, boolean isToogleEnabled) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(TOOGLE, isToogleEnabled);
    editor.apply();
}

public static boolean isToogleEnabled(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return mPrefs.getBoolean(TOOGLE, false);
}

public static boolean isDarkMode(Activity activity) {
    return (activity.getResources().getConfiguration()
            .uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: Starting with AppCompat v1.1.0, setDefaultNightMode() automatically recreates any started activities.