# How to override colorBackground attribute in DayNight theme Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-launcher

I have written a custom style with the DayNight theme as a parent.
I want to override the attribute colorBackground with my own attribute (eg: say Green color for Day mode and Blue color for Night mode). How to achieve it?

`<style name="SampleTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/item</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">**Required** </item>
    </style>`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164414/11158194 this answer for day night mode.